# How to use R to analyze kcore from csv file

Tags: r, csv, sna

Currently, I touched something about SNA and encountered the problem of how to use R to analyze the kcore network from file.

The format of csv file is like below:

//File

```
    PointStart,PointEnd
    jay,yrt
    hiqrr,huame
    Sam,joysunn
    timka,tomdva
    ......,.....
```

I have import this file into R but I do not know next step to handle it.

Thanks for your help geeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `read.csv` to import your data into R data frame, say `d`
2. Use `network` package to create network object with `net <- network(d, directed=TRUE)` with `directed` set to TRUE/FALSE depending on your data.
3. Use `kcores` from sna package (http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sna/functions/kcores): `kcores(net)`.